# playframework 2.x form redirect with prefill

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to implement a user login form, I want to achieve:

1. when username doesn't exist in DB, return a flash message with previous
   form data prefilled.
2. if any server side validation errors happened, return back to previous page, with old data pre-filled, display the errors
   messages along side.

The problem now is, if I use flash scope, I need to use `Redirect` after post, but this will lose the pre-filled data.
If I use any status other than `Redirect`, I can't put data into flash scope.

What did I missing?

Comment: What makes you think you need to use `Redirect` to use flash scope?
[See the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaSessionFlash)

Comment: @DonovanMuller I'm using Play Scala, it gives warning if you're not using flashing with Redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong concept, take a look to the [***Handling form submission***](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms) doc, section: ***Validating a form in an Action***

- If form contains errors you are returning `BadRequest` (not `Redirect`)
- If form IS valid anyway next check (i.e. DB query) returns an error you should do exactly the same thing as in `formWithErrors` so render the view passing incoming form to it (`userData`)
- Finally if everything's OK, you can make your operation and redirect the user i.e. to main page or something...

Pseudo code (basing on doc):

```
def userPost = Action { implicit request =>

  userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      BadRequest(views.html.user(formWithErrors))
    },
    userData => {
      // Check whatever you need...
      if (afterCheckSomethingIsWrong){
        // if something's wrong fill the `userForm` with `userData` and render the same view again...
        // You can use flash scope here i.e. for placing error message
        BadRequest(views.html.user(userForm.fill(userData))).flashing("error" -> "The account doesn't exist")
      } else {
        // if everything is OK, redirect to some page, outside the form handling process, i.e. main page
        Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing("success" -> "Fine you're logged now")
      }

    }
  )

}
```

Comment: I reached to the same conclusion after digging for a few hours. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a `Redirect` for a failed login. You can return the same `Form` back to the login view with extra errors attached to it.

Something like this:

```
loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => views.html.login(formWithErrors),
    credentials => {
         if(authenticate(credentials)) // dummy implementation
             Redirect(controllers.Application.index)
         else
             BadRequest(views.html.login(loginForm.fill(credentials).withGlobalError("Incorrect login credentials")))
    }
)
```

Then your view signature would look something like this:

```
@(loginForm: Form[Credentials])

@* Displays the first global error from the form, if any. *@
@loginForm.globalError.map{error => 
    <h3>@error.message</h3>
}
```

And you'd pre-fill the form with values as before (I hope).

If there are multiple global errors, you can access them with `globalErrors` as it will access a `Seq[FormError]` instead of `Option[FormError]`.

You can also attach errors to specific `Form` keys.

```
 loginForm.withError("email", "I don't like your email.")
```

And would access them similarly:

```
 @loginForm.error("email").map{ error =>
     @error.message
 }
```